# No Audio after motherboard replacement

Tags: 14.04, sound, intel

My laptop's motherboard was replaced recently (overheating) and since then I have lost audio on Ubuntu. The sound card is detected but in sound settings the volume is grayed out and no output (or input) devices are visible in alsamixer although the sound card (onboard) is detected.

[image: Screen cap of alsamixer]

Could this be a hardware issue? I also tried a live CD of Ubuntu on which the same issue was present.

Comment: Hi, i have edited my answer. If the issue has not been resolved try checking my edited answer. I hope it helps. Also does using headphones work?

Answer (score 0):

Try the live cd of the latest ubuntu distro. As that should have a later kernel which may resolve the problem.

EDITED

So newer ubuntu distro live cd didnt work. Have you checked if you have pulseaudio install. Try reinstalling it using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall pulseaudio` then restarting your computer. Also use the dash to open additional drivers, check if there is a driver that your not using. If there is a driver your not using try clicking use and see if that make a difference.